# Generic MVP implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

The idea is to implement MVP structure with base protocols and classes which hold reference to generic view and presenter

```
// --- Base --- //
protocol BaseViewProtocol: class {
    associatedtype P: BasePresenterProtocol
    var presenter: P? { get set }
}
class BaseView<P: BasePresenterProtocol>: UIView, BaseViewProtocol {
    var presenter: P?
}

protocol BasePresenterProtocol {
    associatedtype V: BaseViewProtocol
    weak var view: V? { get set }
}
class BasePresenter<V: BaseViewProtocol>: BasePresenterProtocol {
    weak var view: V?
}

// --- Current --- //
protocol CurrentViewProtocol: BaseViewProtocol {
}
class CurrentView<P: CurrentPresenterProtocol>: BaseView<P>, CurrentViewProtocol {
}

protocol CurrentPresenterProtocol: BasePresenterProtocol {
}
class CurrentPresenter<V: CurrentViewProtocol>: BasePresenter<V>, CurrentPresenterProtocol {
    init(currentView: V) {
        super.init()
        self.view = currentView
    }
}
```

The question is how to instantiate concrete implementation of all these classes, since both View and Presenter are generic classes and depend on each other

Comment: You may want to see this at first: https://github.com/rajagp/iOS_MVC_MVP_MVVM_SampleApp

Comment: @abagmut please explain what u want to achieve ? Where u stuck any example ?

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma I want to have base view with some set of methods and make base presenter able to call them.
All interaction between presenter and view should pass only through interface(protocol)

But I can't create my concrete subclasses like this:

`let view = CurrentView<CurrentPresenterProtocol>()
let presenter = CurrentPresenter<CurrentViewProtocol>(currentView: view)`

Comment: not sure but why u want to create reference cycle situation ?, want to share some code i using in MVP with generic and protocol. Could i ?

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma made view weak, but again it is not production code just conceptual sample

Comment: i can post sample code almost do similar thing could i ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is best way but i had done similar thing in this way

```
  protocol Presentable {
  associatedtype View: ViewAble
  weak var view: View? {get set}

  init(with view: View)

  func onAttach(view: View)
  func onDetach()

   var isAttached: Bool {get}
}

extension Presentable {
  var isAttached: Bool {
    return view != nil
  }
}



class Presenter: Presentable {

 weak var view: ViewAble? {
    didSet {
      if let view = view {
        onAttach(view: view)
      } else {
        onDetach()
      }
    }
  }


  required init(with view: ViewAble) {
    self.view = view
  }

  func onAttach(view: View) {
    //pre set up on construction

  }
  func onDetach() {
    //release some resource on destroying view
  }
}




@objc protocol ViewAble: class {
  @objc optional func showError(_ message: String, _ callBack: (() -> Void)?)
}

extension ViewAble where Self: UIViewController {
  func showAlert(_ message: String?, _ callBack: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
      callBack?()
    })
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: callBack)
  }

  func showLoading() {
    //show default Loading here and override if want custom

  }
  func stopLoading() {
    //stop default Loading
  }
}

class ViewController: ViewAble {

 }
```

Comment: Until you add presenter to View - there are no problems. But if you do so you'll have the same issue as I